# How to draw polyline(MGLPolyline) with dashed lines using mapbox : swift

Tags: swift, mapbox, polyline, mapbox-marker

I tried following code but it draw straight line and i want dashed lines

```
@IBOutlet var navigationView: MGLMapView!
var polyline: MGLPolyline!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var mapCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        let newCoord1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 8.5241, longitude: 76.9366)
        let newCoord2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:11.8745, longitude: 75.3704)

        mapCoordinates.append(newCoord1)
        mapCoordinates.append(newCoord2)

        polyline = MGLPolyline(coordinates: mapCoordinates, count: UInt(mapCoordinates.count))

        navigationView.add(polyline)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use an [`MGLLineStyleLayer`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.2.0/Classes/MGLLineStyleLayer.html), which has a [`lineDashPattern`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.2.0/Classes/MGLLineStyleLayer.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLLineStyleLayer(py)lineDashPattern) property.

[This example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/runtime-add-line/) shows how to add a dashed line, but for your use case, it would look more like:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
            var mapCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
    let newCoord1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 8.5241, longitude: 76.9366)
    let newCoord2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:11.8745, longitude: 75.3704)

    mapCoordinates.append(newCoord1)
    mapCoordinates.append(newCoord2)

    polyline = MGLPolyline(coordinates: mapCoordinates, count: UInt(mapCoordinates.count))

    source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "line", shape: polyline, options: nil)
    style.addSource(source)

    let layer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "line-layer", source: source)
    layer.lineDashPattern = NSExpression(forConstantValue: [2, 1.5])
    style.addLayer(layer)
}
```

Then update the `shape` property on `source` as necessary.